# How can I help my damaged tree survive?

Tags: trees, tree-care

EDIT: added another photo, showing the wound in relation to the main trunk (pink line).

I have an Eastern Redbud tree (Cercis canadensis) that was recently damaged due to the weight of snow. Picture attached. I was thinking it might have to be cut cleanly in front of the break (between the break and the main trunk) to give the tree the best chance of survival. Will that be the best course of action? Will the branches attached to the wound even survive and continue to nourish the tree?  What's the best course of action here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't have knowledge about that particular tree, but if you are cutting the branch, you should aim to do it as close to the main trunk as possible (I would imagine that you will want to cut off that branch - I don't think that branch can recover - and even if it can, the missing part won't grow back/heal - it will be scarred - and the part above it won't get the nutrients it needs)

Comment: Another picture or two at a distance that shows us how the broken branch is positioned in the overall structure would help

Comment: For a conservative approach, cut off what has to go, then wait. Cut off the rest only if it dies.

Comment: > I was thinking it might have to be cut cleanly in front of the break (between the break and the main trunk) to give the tree the best chance of survival

I agree to this approach. A clean cut will limit the risk for infections.